# SQL Server 2014 Lookup value in Table2 between columns

Tags: sql, inner-join, sql-server-2014

I have two tables. In Table A I have a "StartDate" besides other values. I also have a column "TimeZone". In Table B I have TimeZone, StartDST, EndDST (DST=DaylightSavingTime) for several years.

I want to check - if StartDate is in Table B between B.StartDST and B.EndDST. If NOT... it should give me 0 else 1.

TimeZone exists multiple Times in B.

```
FROM DutyList A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TimeZoneDST B 
                  WHERE A.StartDuty between B.DSTstart and B.DSTend))
```

This does not give me all records. I need ALL records from DutyList A.
I need an extra column "DSTexists" 0 or 1 - if StartDuty is in Table B.
I am using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*,
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TimeZoneDST B 
                        WHERE A.StartDuty between B.DSTstart and B.DSTend)
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END as DSTexists
FROM DutyList A;
```